# is creating my own "Horizontal & Vertical Axes" for use with a character controller viable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to recreate the "Horizontal" and "Vertical" default axes that can be found in unity.

The reason I am doing this, is because the way I am doing movement is using a vector2 X and Y values for horizontal & vertical movement, And I want to be able to rebind the keys for movement during run time.

The axes in unity cannot be changed during run time.

Here is what I've made

```
public class HorzontalVerticalVelocity : MonoBehaviour
{

 public float horizontalVelocity;
 public float verticalVelocity;

private void Update()
{
    #region Horizontal

    if (Input.GetKey(GameManager.GM.right))
    {
        if (horizontalVelocity > 1) // Precausion to stop velocity going outside bounds.
        {
            horizontalVelocity = 1;
            return;
        }
        horizontalVelocity += 0.1f;

    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(GameManager.GM.left))
    {
        if (horizontalVelocity < -1)
        {
            horizontalVelocity = -1;
            return;
        }
        horizontalVelocity -= 0.1f;
    }
    else // Reset to zero when no input is recieved.
    {
        if (horizontalVelocity == 0)
            return; // dont run the code if we are stationary!
        horizontalVelocity = Mathf.Lerp(horizontalVelocity, 0, 1f);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Vertical
    if (Input.GetKey(GameManager.GM.up))
    {
        verticalVelocity += 0.1f;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(GameManager.GM.down))
    {
        verticalVelocity -= 0.1f; 
    }
    else // Reset to zero when no input is recieved.
    {
        if (verticalVelocity == 0) 
            return; // dont run the code if we are stationary!
        verticalVelocity = Mathf.Lerp(verticalVelocity, 0, 1f);
    }

    #endregion


    // Clamp velocity to a reasonable limit.
    horizontalVelocity = Mathf.Clamp(horizontalVelocity, -1, 1);
    verticalVelocity = Mathf.Clamp(verticalVelocity, -1, 1);
}
}
```

I have the concept down for the axis, the value gets set, and returns back to zero when there is no input.

However I have noticed a few issues

the major one being it is extremely clunky in comparison to using the unity Horizontal Axis for movement.

Any advice on how I can make this on par to that? or should I just rework the way I am adding velocity on the character at this point.

Comment: I think your main problem is that when you switch from Left to Right you don't immediately jump to zero before doing your ramp up, which makes the controls feel sluggish.

Comment: ahh yes I forgot about something so simple! it does help a great deal with making it feel smooth.